# How to have an IIS Application run a simple command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

So, let's say you have a website in IIS called `Test`. I want to be able to add an Application that simply runs `foo.exe /runfoo` when a user visits the page. Let's say I don't care about performance, "clean code", running the command too often, etc. This is for a proof-of-concept / part of a bigger toolkit.

What I have tried and have working is that I can deploy a full C# Web App with all the DLLs/other junk, and have it create a `Process` and run it. I don't want to have to do that. The ideal scenario is that I would create an Application under an existing website which has a separate app pool (that I can change), and within that I could modify the web.config or something to do with the app pool to have it run a command. A simple Application, with a single folder, with minimal files in it.

Some requirements:

- The command can run regularly rather than only when a user visits a page, but that's not as preferable.
- The command must be able to take arguments.
- Minimal files needed in the Application directory.

I've looked through all of the existing options I could find, and none of them stuck out to me as something that'd be useful for this except the "Process Orphaning" in the App Pool settings. Is there a way to trigger this by visiting the page (without deploying a full-fledged web app)?

Comment: The down-votes tell me that the community feels like my question either doesn't show research effort, is unclear, or not useful. I have put a lot of effort into researching solutions to this problem, and stated methods which don't work for me (deploying a full application). I have poured over the IIS documentation sites I could find, and it just isn't something people normally do. If anything is unclear, please comment and let me know what needs clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Looks like this is a research work doing on offensive security technique and what this requirements from IIS

- The command can run regularly rather than only when a user visits a
  page, but that's not as preferable.
- The command must be able to take
  arguments.
- Minimal files needed in the Application directory.

You can run an exe as CGI executable in IIS as explained [here](https://blogs.iis.net/thomad/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5) . [This](http://chalaki.com/8-steps-program-install-setup-call-csharp-cgi-programs-in-iis-7/321/) article talks about passing query string value . Also explore [fastCGI](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/fastcgi-for-iis) as well for an improvement on CGI

**Edit 2:Adding another option**

> You can also simply put a simple aspx and it's code behind in a IIS
>   website's content and can access that aspx page. No Compilation,No
>   deployment,no bin directory etc.All you need is two files

- Create two files default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs inside your IIS website

Here's the code

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and Default.aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Process process = new Process();            
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "echo.exe";            
            process.Start();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you are intending to come off as snarky, but I am familiar with scheduled tasks. This is part of research of an offensive security technique, and I want to be able to demonstrate a simple proof-of-concept. Deploying an entire website is not ideal, and using schtasks, registry entries, the `at` command, WMI event subscriptions, etc are not suitable alternatives. I understand that what I am asking for sounds like "bad practice" but I would ask that the community give me the benefit of the doubt that I have a reason for doing something so odd.

Comment: ohh my bad.I was thinking that ur requirement is what ur requirement listed.You shud add that details to the question  that this is part of research of an security technique.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, but this would require enabling the CGI module in IIS, right? That is a bit too invasive for my liking. I understand that this was not listed as a requirement or anything, but I assumed there would be a simpler method somehow. I'm seeing if I can maybe just add a simple page/dll combo that has relative path references to an existing site for all of the other .NET dlls and stuff.

Comment: yes,you are right.Technically you can rename html page as aspx and aspnet compiler will compile that and run it.Will update the answer with details

Comment: Hmm, yeah. I think that's actually the way to do it (very close at least). In my example, there's a main website with a low privs app pool running. What I do is create an app pool that runs as Local System, Create an application that uses that app pool, add a symbolic link to the bin directory of the main application, and then drop in an aspx file like you said. I did a little testing, and that seems to work. Not 100% what you were saying, but this is for running under a different app pool. Your method should certainly work if we want the program running as the IIS_USR. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just in case you are interested, the tool can be found here: https://github.com/pmood/IISplant Thanks again.